# One-To-Many relationship, loading children breaks in Hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate

I have an existing relationship that was working in Hibernate 5 but with Hibernate 6 it breaks when the child entities are attempted to be loaded.

Question (Parent):

```
@Id
@Column(name = "QUESTIONCODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 12)
private String     questionCode;

@Id
@Column(name = "OWNERID", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
private BigInteger ownerId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "question")
@Cascade(value = {CascadeType.ALL})
@OrderBy(clause = "ANSWERCODE")
private Set<Answer> answers;
```

Answer (Child):

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "QUESTIONCODE", referencedColumnName = "QUESTIONCODE")
@JoinColumn(name = "OWNERID", referencedColumnName = "OWNERID")
private Question question;

@Id
@Column(name = "ANSWERCODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 12)
private String answerCode;
```

After loading a Question, calling getAnswers makes a query:
`select q1_0.OWNERID,q1_0.QUESTIONCODE,q1_0.ANSWERCODE from ANSWERS q1_0 where (q1_0.OWNERID=? and q1_0.QUESTIONCODE=?) order by q1_0.ANSWERCODE`

Looks good! But it logs this error:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An error occurred during the current command (Done status 0). Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A question code' to data type int.`

Using SQL Profiler, I found that Hibernate is sending this query to SQL Server:

`exec sp_executesql N'select q1_0.OWNERID,q1_0.QUESTIONCODE,q1_0.ANSWERCODE from ANSWERS q1_0 where (q1_0.OWNERID=@P0 and q1_0.QUESTIONCODE=@P1) order by q1_0.ANSWERCODE',N'@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 decimal(38,0)',N'A question code',99`

**It's swapping the types and values for @P0 and @P1!** Maybe this is just a bug but I'm wondering if this is the wrong way to define this relationship given that all the columns involved are also part of the primary key, and Hibernate 6 is just being more strict about it.

Update:

Then I tried adding a join to remove the second query to retrieve answers. It swaps the columns in the join and fails the same way!

`select q1_0.QUESTIONCODE,q1_0.OWNERID,q2_0.OWNERID,q2_0.QUESTIONCODE,q2_0.ANSWERCODE from QUALIFIERQUESTIONS q1_0 left join QUALIFIERANSWERS q2_0 on q1_0.QUESTIONCODE=q2_0.OWNERID and q1_0.OWNERID=q2_0.QUESTIONCODE where q1_0.OWNERID=? order by q1_0.QUESTIONCODE asc,q2_0.ANSWERCODE`

Meanwhile I'm trying to reproduce this in a simple Java app and it's working fine there. The error occurs in a Spring Boot 3.1.0 app.